# What does darktable noiseprofiling read_pfm parameters mean?

Tags: darktable

I'm trying to analysis darktable. I'm windows user.

I found the usage of darktable like as following on noiseprofile.c.

```
 usage : input.pfm [-c a1 b1]
```

Here, I want to know the c and a1 and b1.

Q1.What is this?

Q2.What do those mean?

Q3.How can we get information and parameters above parameters?

Q4.Can we make above 3 parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: vtc b/c Q is a programming question about the source code of a raw-processing program, not its use for photography.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about C programming.

Answer (score 1):

Mild rewording of the question to follow.

You are asking about [this line](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/321c02892f8c5d1038cd6d558b676bdf2ece34ca/tools/noise/noiseprofile.c#L155) in the Darktable source code, and I applude that you are investigating the software at that level.

It's part of this section:

```
int main(int argc, char *arg[])
{
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s input.pfm [-c a1 b1]\n", arg[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  int wd, ht;
float *input = read_pfm(arg[1], &wd, &ht);
```

And the fragment broadly reads "if the program is started without enought arguments, then print an error message giving the normal usage.

I think you've slightly misread the command. It should be along the lines of

```
./noiseprofile input.pfm
```

...and then an optional height and width.

I don't actually think this is a photography question (it's certainly far from a photography answer) so I'm voting to close on that basis...